# Creting a graphical process control panel

Tags: python, graphics, controls, panel, gekko

Dear Professor Hedengren and community:

I was wondering if Gekko (or Python as a bigger entity) has any way to convert simulations into a graphical control panel.

Say we have a Combined Cycle, and we want to calculate the net efficiency by altering the process parameters, such as pressure levels, stack temperature, air/fuel ratio at the combustor...

Please find attached a sketch on what I mean with this.

This would be especially interesting for non-experienced users, for them to grasp an insight on how these parameters affect the output, without diving into the formalities of coding / Thermodynamics.

Thanks in advance for your valuable time.

Best regards,
Enrique Garcia - Spain

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to create this graphical panel is through [IPython widgets](http://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/TCLabPIControlTuning) if you are running in a Jupyter notebook. Here is an [example with Python and APM](http://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/EstimatorTuning) although you could just as easily create this with Gekko.

[image: MHE Widget]

A built-in option for Gekko is the `GUI` interface that can be accessed with `m.solve(GUI=True)`. There is [more information on the GUI interface in the Gekko paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2227-9717/6/8/106).